# static property sharing/defining between children in PHP classes

Tags: php, oop, static

I'm facing a misunderstanding about what the title describe and i'd like to know if there is another way to achieve what I'm looking for there.
I have an abstract class which declare a static property without value, and I instanciate subclasses from it that are defining the value of that static property. The base class also define another static property value depending of the first one, but the problem is subclasses are losing their first property value for the last one defined in other subclasses and then this second property get the bad value from the parent class.

This code demonstrate it better than I explain:

```
abstract class A
{
    protected static $name; 
    protected static $path;

    public function __construct()
    {
        static::$path = static::$name."Path";
    }

    public function getPath()
    {
        return static::$path;   
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    protected static $name = "B";   
}

class C extends A
{
    protected static $name = "C";   
}

$b = new B();
$c = new C();

echo $b->getPath();
```

I expected the echo to print "Bpath", but unfortunately it prints "CPath". 
If I comment the line that instanciate the C class, then the print is good.

**EDIT:**
The thing is if i do this code :

```
abstract class A
{   
    protected static $name;
    protected static $path;

    public function __construct()
    {
        static::$path = static::$name."Path";
    }

    public function getPath()
    {
        return static::$path;   
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return static::$name;   
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    protected static $name = "B";   
}

class C extends A
{
    protected static $name = "C";   
}

$b = new B();
$c = new C();

echo $b->getName();
```

The name printed is "B" and good. So the fact of redefining value in subclass property doesn't have the same consequence of doing it in constructor, even if using static:: keyword.

Comment: Because property is __static__.

Comment: You probably want to set `$this->path = static::$name . 'Path'` to set an instance property, not overwrite the shared static property.

Comment: When you are using instances, why would you want to work with static variables?

Comment: So redefining the property value directly in the subclass doesn't have the same effect as in the constructor, according to this (=> edited post)

Comment: @MarkusZeller in the first time it was to have access to it from everywhere, while they were public and not protected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The static property `$path` is only defined once on class `A`. Setting `static::$path` from anywhere will always set `A::$path`, so the value is shared among all classes.

You'd see a different result if you declared `protected static $path;` on both child classes, e.g.:

```
class B extends A {
    protected static $name = "B";   
    protected static $path;
}
```

Now each class would have its own static `$path` property and they could be set independently.

It would make much more sense to use an instance property though instead of this bending over backwards with static properties:

```
abstract class A {
    protected static $name;
    protected $path;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->path = static::$name . 'Path';
    }

    public function getPath() {
        return $this->path;   
    }
}
```